# .htaccess redirects to subdomain with %{REQUEST_FILENAME}

Tags: .htaccess

We have an online shopping cart that was installed into root - we then decided that we wanted to install a CMS ito root and move the shopping cart to a subdomain.

So we have

1. domain.com
2. shop.domain.com

What we are trying to achieve is to redirect URLs that are as follows:

```
domain.com/product_info.php?products_id=X
```

To:

```
shop.domain.com/product_info.php?products_id=X
```

Where the value of X needs to change as well.

I read (and if I understand this correctly) it would have something to do with `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` and so far we have this in our `.htaccess`, which was a wildcard redirect which is actually redirecting everything to the same file name but we want the value of X to change too.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.co.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.co.uk$
RewriteRule ^product_info\.php\/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\/sub.domain\.co.uk\/product_info\.php\?products_id\=1$1" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: So if URL is `domain.com/product_info.php?products_id=10` what will be target URL? Is it not `http://shop.domain.com/product_info.php?products_id=10` ??

Comment: @anubhava I think he/she meant to say that X is not a fixed value that's why `will change`

Comment: @Prix: Probably you are right but `products_id\=1$1` in OP's code was utter confusing :P

Comment: @anubhava well added both just in case. Yeah so many unneeded escaping +_+

Comment: @Prix: +1 for your detailed answer.

Comment: Yes the target url would also be http://shop.domain.com/product_info.php?products_id=10 as anubhava suggested. For each product in the shop the products id will change so we want it to go to the subdomain - the target url but with the corresponding product id

Comment: @Prix, the solution you gave me was correct. Thank You for your assistance, not only have you helped me, but I've just learn something new and am now just that little bit more wiser. Thank You Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `QSA` flag will automatically pass the query string back, put this `.htaccess` on the root folder of your domain:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^product_info\.php$ http://shop.domain.co.uk/product_info.php [R=301,QSA,L]
```

If the subdomain is also on the same root folder of your domain, then use this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^product_info\.php$ http://shop.domain.co.uk/product_info.php [R=301,QSA,L]
```

So basically with any of the above rules, if the user access:

```
domain.com/product_info.php?products_id=4
domain.com/product_info.php?products_id=3
domain.com/product_info.php?products_id=2
domain.com/product_info.php?products_id=1
```

It will be redirected to:

```
shop.domain.com/product_info.php?products_id=4
shop.domain.com/product_info.php?products_id=3
shop.domain.com/product_info.php?products_id=2
shop.domain.com/product_info.php?products_id=1
```

---

If you in fact need to change the ID this is how you would do it:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} products_id=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^product_info\.php$ http://shop.domain.co.uk/product_info.php?products_id=1%1 [R=301,L]
```

And if the domain and sub domain are on the same root folder this is how it would look like:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} products_id=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^product_info\.php$ http://shop.domain.co.uk/product_info.php?products_id=1%1 [R=301,L]
```

Basically you need to use `%{QUERY_STRING}` to get data from the query string.

So with any of the 2 above rules, if the user access:

```
domain.com/product_info.php?products_id=4
domain.com/product_info.php?products_id=3
domain.com/product_info.php?products_id=2
domain.com/product_info.php?products_id=1
```

It will be redirected to:

```
shop.domain.com/product_info.php?products_id=14
shop.domain.com/product_info.php?products_id=13
shop.domain.com/product_info.php?products_id=12
shop.domain.com/product_info.php?products_id=11
```